# Unable to run API in postman

Tags: api, rest

Trying to run an API to get the list of all customers in a site. Getting the error:
"Sorry,authentication failed. The authorization header for basic authentication not present in request"

Unsure what to enter in the Key field under Authentication:

[image]

I have changed the Add to to Header and performing a get request it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the authorization key or token to run the API in Postman. For this, you need to import the key/token in the headers before writing the API to get all customers

Comment: I have added the Key in the value section but unsure what goes in the Key Field.

For ex, when using OpenweatherAPI the Key field = appid

Comment: The value of the key you need to add the token that you get from the api from where you get the customer list.

Comment: Ilke when you login to the portal of customers you need to get a token in the response and add them in the key there

Answer (score 0):

In Postman, you have a dedicated Authorization tab in which you can select the type of authentication needed. In your case, you should choose in the list "Basic Auth" and then enter your username and password.

This option will format and encode the Authorization value properly (encoding username:password in base64)

This is equivalent of using the Headers tab and entering "Authorization" as the key and "Basic *base64*". (If you use the Authorization tab, you will be able to see the generated header by showing the hidden headers)